# what is the parameter passing to the OnClickListener()?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to java with C family background. 
I'm unable to dissect this code. If only you could help me by identifying what are the inner classes and interfaces in this block:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View view)
        {         
                              
        usrnameobj = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_usename);
           usrpassobj = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_password); 
        String username = usrnameobj.getText().toString(); 
        String password = usrpassobj.getText().toString(); 
        
        Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AndroidXmlResource.class);
        i.putExtra("entry",username.toString() + password.toString());
        startActivityForResult(i,REQ_CODE);
      
        }  
       });
```

I can only imagine up to:

```
startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

but nothing between { }

Comment: I would not say it is a good question, but it is a cute question....

Comment: not cute for someone habitual of creating objects before passing them as arguments :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnClickListener is an *interface* defined into the View *class*. Imagine it like this:

```
class View
{
    static interface OnClickListener
    {
        public void onClick(View v);
    }
}
```

The thing between {} is the implementation of the method `onClick(View)` of the `OnClickListener` interface. The thing between () starting with `new...` is called *anonymous inner class*. You may find more clarifications [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html).

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

It creates an anonymous class that implements the `View.OnClickListener` interface.  You would do this when you need to receive and process the clicks on the `View` but don't want to have to create a formal class for this simple process (you'd end up with many of them).

Check out [this](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm) explanation of anonymous classes.

Answer (score 2):

What is sent in there is an anonymous class, you could just as well make a separate class which implements OnClickListener and make an instance of that class and send that in as the argument to setOnClickListener.

"public void onClick(View view)" is the function which needs to be overridden, and that's what gets called when the class you setOnClickListener gets clicked. So in this case it fetches password and username from your form and starts the activity for the intent set.

Answer (score 1):

`setOnClickListener` method takes a new `View.OnClickListener()` instance as parameter and what is happening inside the curly brackets is overriding the `onClick()` method of that class. I think you can dissect the `onClick()` method easily.

Answer (score 0):

The sample code mentioned contains an anonymous inner class .

Here the username & password data is being fetched & the next Activity is being called when the user is clicking on the Start button.

Kindly check the following url :

**http://www.remwebdevelopment.com/dev/a69/Different-Ways-To-Handle-Clicks.html**

Kindly revert for any clarifications

Answer (score 0):

You can do 
either

```
    btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then out of onCreate() do

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.Button:
        //do what you like to do
        break;
    }
 }
```

or

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                            // do what you like to do
        }

 });
```